# Use OR Operator Between Two GPIO on python

Tags: raspbian, python, rpi.gpio

I am writing a short program in Python on the Raspberry Pi, to stop a while loop by any of the one GPIO from two, but it is not stopping the loop. Although, if I use GPIO individually its successfully work.

Both my GPIO(23) and GPIO(24) are working fine,

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while (GPIO.input(23) or GPIO.input(24)) == True:
    print ("Loop")

print ("Stop")
```

Can you please guide me on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: why you on hold without given any reason/answer

Comment: If you look at the help center link, "Questions about programming that are not related to its usage on the Raspberry Pi" are off-topic.  This is sort of ambiguous; what it means is, programming questions that don't depend on some special facility of the pi.  This one doesn't -- you're asking a basic question about how to write a `while` loop with two conditions.  If you were claiming the loop doesn't work because of something odd about RPi.GPIO, then it would be appropriate here...

Comment: ...The reason for these restrictions are that we don't have the resources to be teaching people python, and it is better for you to be asking somewhere that they do.

Comment: In addition to what was previously said by @goldilocks. I did not put it on hold until you had gotten an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (GPIO.input(23) == True) or (GPIO.input(24) == True):
   print ("Loop")
```

Comment: I tried above code, but not working

Comment: How about w/ `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: start working, it was my GPIO setting ... thank you